# ACF only showing up in Homepage but doesn't appears in all pages

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I create a group field for "contact info" and define to edit it only in Homepage.
[image]

And it works on Homepage. But if I go to another page of the website, the fields just disappear
[image]

My code for contact info in header.php is:

```
        <header>

        <section class="container-top">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <span>
                    <?php the_field( 'telefone_header' ); ?>            
                </span>
                <a href="mailto:<?php the_field( 'email_header' ); ?>">
                    <?php the_field( 'email_header' ); ?>
                </a>

                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="container-header">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h1>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="Limpen">
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/images/limpen.jpg" alt="Limpen">
                    </a>
                </h1>
                <nav>
                <?php wp_nav_menu ( array (
                        'container' => false,
                        'items_wrap' => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
                        'walker' => new My_Walker_Nav_Menu()
                    )
                ); ?>
                    <div class="ico-menu"></div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </section>

    </header>
```

And for the footer.php is:

```
<div class="links">
                    <strong>
                        Fale Conosco
                    </strong>
                    <div class="info">
                        <strong>
                            <?php the_field( 'titulo_empresa' ); ?>
                        </strong>
                        <a href="mailto:<?php the_field( 'email_empresa' ); ?>"><?php the_field( 'email_empresa' ); ?></a>
                        <span><?php the_field( 'telefones_empresa' ); ?></span>
                        <address>
                            <?php the_field( 'endereco_empresa' ); ?>
                        </address>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: proper place to ask it is ACF support

Comment: asked there too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the ID of the page as the second argument.

E.G If your home page has a page ID of 1, you need to do:

```
the_field('field_name', 1);
```

See here for more information on the_field.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/

Comment: Thank you Steve! I updated the line of code with the page ID in both (header.php and footer.php) and now it works on all pages.